# Merge multiple maps in kinetic

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you merge multiple maps (generated by map_server map_saver) to form a single map?

I want to generate a single map of a building with high accuracy. Then I will use the map in AMCL for localization

1. Place the LIDAR in a known position
2. Generate the scan map using gmapping with the known position
3. Move to a new known position by moving the LIDAR manually
4. Repeat 2 until the entire building is mapped
5. Merge the maps to a single map

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292057/merge-multiple-maps-in-kinetic/) by [Archhaskeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/29156/archhaskeller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm serching for live map merging at the moment. I use multirobot_map_merger at the moment. (Works not well till the moment for me).
But https://github.com/ahhda/Map-Merge-Tool may help you. It's made to merge two map pictures.

---

Originally posted by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) with karma: 272 on 2019-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1